# Write frames to RTSP/HTTP using FFMPEG

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have an application that reads footage from an RTSP stream and processes the frames. I need to restream these processed frames to another RTSP stream. I have used the following command to stream a video file using FFMPEG:
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i D:\Proj\sample.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://10.0.0.0:8554/mystream.
Is it possible to stream individual frames as soon as they are processed and not only a full video file?
The algorithm has been built in MATLAB.

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible using FFmpeg as sub-process with stdin and stdout pipes. Using pipes in a MATLAB script requires some JAVA code.

Comment: Be sure to format code with backticks.  Good formatting  improves  readability